# How to get columnar minimums in a list of arrays?

Tags: c#, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of doubles stored in a list as shown below. I want to get the minimum from each of the columns. I know i can somehow loop through list and get the minimums. But, is there a simpler way to get the same using the List.Min() from each of the columns??

```
List<double[]> BoxCoords = new List<double[]>();

<!-----------------Console output of BoxCoords List------------------------------!>

 8.03698858873275  | -1622.419367705   | 180.603950687759   //List Entry 1
 8.03698858855283  | -1622.41905090503 | -220.203952098008  //List Entry 2 
-7.70512234523364  | -1665.73116372802 | -220.204298594721  //List Entry 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your columns are defined by the ordinals of the wrapped arrays, and not by the values in each row, here's a method using the [`index` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) of `Select`, to unpivot the data (with `SelectMany`), and then re-grouping the data on the indexes, after which applying `Min` is a formality:

```
var columnMins = BoxCoords
    .SelectMany(bc => bc.Select((v, idx) => new {Idx = idx, Val = v}))
    .GroupBy(up => up.Idx)
    .Select(grp => grp.Min(x => x.Val));
```

You can add `.ToArray()` at the end if you need this back as an array of `double`

> [-7.70512234523364, -1665.73116372802, -220.204298594721]

**Demo [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQVR3t)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know how the code works actually, but it worked perfect for me:)

Comment: Won't this return an enumerable of anonymous type?

Comment: Basically, we  'transpose' the original data structure by unpivotting it into a flattened set of tuples, but at the same time remembering the position in the row (using the Select overload). After that its as simple as re-grouping on our index and applying the aggregate. @Kapol, no, I'm projecting out just the Min of `x.Val`, which is a double, so it will be `IEnumerable<double>` or `double[]` if OP tacks on a `.ToArray()`

Answer (score 6):

for row:

```
List<double[]> BoxCoords = new List<double[]>();
var result = BoxCoords.Select(x=>x.Min()).ToList();
```

for column:

```
var result = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < BoxCoords[0].Length; i++)//care! exception for jugged arrays
{
    result.Add(BoxCoords.SelectMany(x => x.Skip(i).Take(1).ToList()).ToList().Min());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tested this, but it returns the minimum from a row, not a column. I need the minimum from each column